# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" when running on another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, twitter, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to use TweetSharp from a static class (called `TitterHandler`) so theoretically I can swap it out later.

The example suggests using `Dispatch.BeginInvoke` so when the UI is updated it is done using the UI thread.

I would like to just load data into the model, although admittedly this will trigger an `OnPropertyChanged` event which will update the UI. Since this is from a static method I use `System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.

However it keeps crashing with an 'Object not set to a reference ' exception. I have fairly limited understanding of threads but from what I gather

- The UI thread needs to update the UI but the main thread may fire an event which is then picked up by the UI thread - to test this I assign to a static variable totally separate from the UI (`TweetCache`) but the app still crashes
- The thread may be garbage collected if there are no references to it. I placed a reference (`Thread`) on the class but still it crashes.

I am out of ideas, here is the code ...

```
public class TwitterHandler
{

    public static TwitterService Service = new TwitterService(AppConfig.TwitterConsumerKey, AppConfig.TwitterConsumerSecret);

    internal static void LoadTweetsFromWeb()
    {
        TwitterHandler.Service.AuthenticateWith(AppConfig.TwitterToken, AppConfig.TwitterTokenSecret);
        TwitterHandler.Service.ListTweetsOnUserTimeline(new ListTweetsOnUserTimelineOptions() 
            { ScreenName = AppConfig.NewsBrandingTwitterHandle, }, 
            TwitterHandler.OnTweetsLoaded);
    }


    // Put this here to maintain a refrence to the thread to avoid GC
    public static DispatcherOperation Thread;

    // A 'thread external' reference with no onward events that trigger UI changes
    public static List<Tweet> TweetCache;

    public static void OnTweetsLoaded(IEnumerable<TwitterStatus> statuses, TwitterResponse res)
    {
        if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            TwitterHandler.Thread = System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                List<Tweet> tweets = new List<Tweet>();
                foreach (TwitterStatus status in statuses)
                {
                    tweets.Add(new Tweet()
                    {
                        Content = status.Text,
                        UrlString = status.Place.Url,
                    });
                }
                if (tweets.Count > 0)
                {
                    // App.Tweets = tweets;
                    // TweetCache raises no 'PropertyChanged' event
                    TwitterHandler.TweetCache = tweets;
                }

            });
        }


    }




}
```

Comment: Where (at which line)  does it throw the exception?

Comment: The exception is really vague (missing a 'pdb' object), when I stepped through it went dead at the `foreach` loop when adding statuses ...

Comment: `status.Place` is guaranteed to be not null?

Comment: Damnit you are right. The `Place` parameter is not what I though it was and is null - It's really annoying that the debugger stops giving useful info inside a thread - make an answer and I'll close out the question ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: @Soner Heh that'd a great SO question. I know what Null Reference is but the problem with threads is that I automatically assume it is something deeper 'because threads' and the FUD surrounding them ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our shared debug powers revealed that `status.Place` is null.

(other options could be but are less likely: the caller disposes `statuses` member)